# What is the name of this heart-like decorative symbol?

Tags: symbols

I occasionally come across a symbol that looks like this:

[image]

It looks to me like some sort of stylized heart, or maybe some kind of fruit on a branch.  It is often used to separate blocks of text, for example on book covers that are trying to appear elegant.  I most recently saw it in [this New York Times Op-Art by Ben Schott](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/02/24/opinion/sunday/ben-schott-movies-billing-blocks.html?smid=pl-share) (may require subscription).

Does this symbol have a name?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Generically, it's called a "fleuron". Some specifically call it an "aldus leaf".

A fleuron is essentially an ornamental typographic character. The Aldus Leaf being a commonly used one.

More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleuron_(typography)